Boot and dual boot
After using windows for years, I wanted to try Ubuntu.
I downloaded the last version 24.04, prepared the USB flash, prepared unallocated partition then started to install. Every thing goes right, I had chosen the double Boot. Every thing OK until completed and the system asked me to restart.
After removing the USB flash and  restarting, my PC started in windows (11) without any appearance of Ubuntu?
I reattached the flash and rebooted and I find the option to try or install Ubuntu again, I chose that and found it started the previous steps all over again as if it didn't installed and asked me for all the steps for setup again, (location, language etc....).
I assured that the unallocated partition now contains the Ubuntu system.
Have you an explanation and solution? I expected on starting up my PC to see an option to choose an operating system to start either Ubuntu or Windows.

When you made the boot USB media did you configure for EFI?

HP is special in that case, what is your computer brand and model? Have you stopped windows fast startup?

It is common mistake I guess after dual boot your bios have 2 options either to boot into windows or boot into ubuntu. I think by default your pc is in windows just try changing boot order or boot into Linux for that instance. If you provide some more info about the pc i might help you further.
